# Probability of picking a Friday in July

Tags: probability

So my teacher asked me this question. What is the probability that someone chooses Friday (or any other day for that matter) in the month of July. I thought about it but it doesn't look that easy.

I got a 52/217 by adding 1/7 and 3/31. Can you please help?

The choice of all days is all days of the week.

And my calculation does not have a logic. That is what I need.
The only thing is I got it this way.

First I took February which has 28 days. The probability becomes 1/7.
Then I took February in a leap year and I thought the probability should become 2/7 (because of an extra day).

But then I assumed a month with 35 days. According to my logic it would mean 1/7 + 7/7 (because of the 7 extra days) which would be wrong.

Basically my calculation is wrong probably.

Comment: Could you please calrify what is the choice to be made; that what is the collection of all days that are available for the choice. And what is your reasoning behind the calculation.

Comment: Are you talking about July or February? The first part indicates July, but the latter part talks about February.

Answer (score 3):

The question as you have asked it is ambiguous.  The fundamental idea of probability theory is you need to specify what are the objects you are choosing from (with all choices equally likely), and which choices are considered "desirable".

1. You are choosing a random day in a specific July, e.g. July 2014, and want to know the probability it's Friday.  Then you count the number of Fridays and divide by the number of days in that month, to get $\frac{4}{31}$.
2. You are choosing a random day in the year, e.g. 2014, and want to know the probability it's a Friday in July.  Then you count the number of Fridays in July and divide by the number of days, to get $\frac{4}{365}$.
3. You are choosing what to eat for breakfast, and want to know the probability that you pick a Friday in July.  Then the answer is $0$.

The only time you would add probabilities, as in the OP, is if you are adding the probabilities of disjoint events.  For example, if Event 1 is as in #1, and Event 2 is choosing a Tuesday in July 2014.  Event 1 is $\frac{4}{31}$ while Event 2 is $\frac{5}{31}$, so the probability of choosing a (Friday or Tuesday) is $\frac{4}{31}+\frac{5}{31}=\frac{9}{31}$.

Comment: But is there a general answer? I mean if the 2014 (the year) is not specific?

Comment: No, as the number of fridays in july is dependent upon what year it is.  Some years there are 4, other years there are 5

Comment: In addition some years have 366 days.

Comment: If the year is unspecified (but after the Gregorian reform), and the Gregorian calendar continues forever (which it won't) we can find the limit as $n$ goes to infinity of the proportion of July days from $2014$ to $2014+n-1$ that are Fridays. This is because the Gregorian calendar cycles every $400$ years.

Answer (score 0):

Your question could use some more detail, so for now I'm assuming that you are interested in the probability of a Friday in July with an unspecified year.

**Hint**: First calculate the number of Fridays that can occur in July. Is that number always the same? To figure this out, first count the number of Fridays in July if July $1^{st}$ is a Friday. Repeat for the case that July $2^{nd}$ is a Friday. Repeat this process all the way through until you have figured out how many Fridays there will be in July if the first Friday is on the $7^{th}$. Now add up the total number of Fridays for each of the seven cases, and divide that number by $31 \cdot 7 = 217$. You can generalize this process for any day of the week.

If you are given a specific year and month, just check a calendar for that year in the month in question, count the number of Fridays that occur in that month and divide by the number of days in that month.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is Prob = 1/7 ?

Essentially if there is no assumption about which year...then all days of the week are the same as each other. Every choice of date will result in one of the 7 days of the week. Therefore 1/7